# java read write unicode / UTF-8 filenames (not contents)

Tags: java, macos, encoding, filenames

i have a few directories/files with Japanese characters. If i try to read a filename (not the contents) containing (as example) a ク i receive a String containing a �. If i try to create a file/directory containing an ク a file/directory appears containing a ?.

As example:
I list the files with.

```
File file = new File(".");  
String[] filesAndDirs = file.list();
```

the filesAndDirs array now contains the directories this the special characters. The String now only contains ����. It seams there is nothing to decode because the a getbytes shows only "-17 -65 -67" for every char in the filename even for different chars.

I use MacOS 10.8.2 Java 7_10 and Netbeans.

Any ideas?

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: It's not clear *how* you're showing those filenames or whether you're providing an encoding for `String.getBytes()` (which you always should). You should dump out the UTF-16 code point for each character in the filename, to see what's really going on. Also, it's not clear how you were getting the input data when trying to create the file.

Comment: `getBytes` returns what seems to be valid UTF8

Comment: @Jan Yes it seems like valid UT8 but getBytes returns "-17 -65 -67" for every char. But not all chars in the file/directory name are the same. It seems as if i loose all information between the OS and the JavaVM. "-17 -65 -67" is repeated for every Special char. [a-zA-Z ...] are returned as expected. I would at least expect different bytes for each char.

Comment: Perhaps it's valid UTF8 for �?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those bytes are 0xef 0xbf 0xbd, which is the UTF-8-encoded form of the \ufffd character you're seeing instead of the Japanese characters.  It appears whatever OS function Java is using to list the files is in fact returning those incorrect characters.

Perhaps Files.newDirectoryStream will be more reliable.  Try this instead:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."))) {
    for (Path child : dir) {
        String filename = child.getFileName().toString();

        System.out.println("name=" + filename);
        for (char c : filename.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.printf("%04x ", (int) c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: working like a charm :). Now i only have to find out how to create files and folders with special chars. Thank You very much!

Comment: Have a look at the javadoc for the `Files` class.  It has methods to do all of those things.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the old java File api (maybe just on a mac).  Anyway, it's all fixed in the new java.nio.

I have several files containing unicode characters in the filename and content that failed to load using java.io.File and related classes.  After converting all my code to use [java.nio.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) EVERYTHING started working.  And I replaced org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils (which has the same problem) with [java.nio.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)...

...and be sure to read and write the content of file using an appropriate charset, for example: Files.readAllLines(myPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)