# Cannot write chinese characters to a filename

Tags: java, file, internationalization

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = in.nextLine();

    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/"+fileName+".txt"), "UTF-8"));//Ex thrown
    out.close();
}
```

I'm trying to create a writer that can handle chinese characters to the file name. So I can create a file called `你好.txt` for example.

However I get a `FileNotFoundException`  with the above code, it works perfectly fine for English characters but not with Chinese characters.

I followed the answers here: [How to write a UTF-8 file with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java) to produce the above code but it doesn't work.

Anyone know how can I accomplish this?

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\temp\??.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Using NIO:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/temp/"+fileName+".txt");//throws ex
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Path file = Files.createFile(path);
BufferedWriter  bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset);
bufferedWriter.close();
```

Stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 8: C:/temp/?.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I believe this is OS-dependent.  OS's control what strings are allowable as file names.  What OS are you using?  P.S. OS's don't particularly care what bytes are in the file's data; that's up to the apps that read the files.  That's why the link you tried to follow won't help you.

Comment: Can you please provide stackTrace ?

Comment: @TAsk Added stack trace and indicated in sscce which line throws it

Comment: @ajb 你好.txt is a valid file name, if I make it through explorer (windows 8) I have no problems, only if I try and make it through code.

Comment: You should also set the charset for the `scanner`. Change it to `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");` and try.

Comment: @Codebender did not work

Comment: @Aequitas, are you still receiving the same exception with `C:\temp\??.txt`

Comment: @Codebender yep it's exactly the same stack trace.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as) might be relevant; NTFS itself uses UTF-16, and there are weird specific steps that you have to take on Windows to get certain characters working. The JRE might not be using those calls.

Comment: Also, please post the `\uXXXX` values for the characters you're trying to use.

Comment: Looking into it, it appears you cannot make this work with `java.io`, but `java.nio` will work.  Still don't know all the details.

Comment: @chrylis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_Unified_Ideographs,_part_1_of_4 the few I tested here don't work, specifically the first one I tested (一)

Comment: @ajb I have a very strong suspicion that NTFS requires explicit encoding steps for high-code characters, and that those steps were implemented in NIO but not (for backwards compatibility) retrofitted.

Comment: @chrylis one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171565/java-read-write-unicode-utf-8-filenames-not-contents) seems to support your suspicion.

Comment: @chrylis I tried using NIO and no luck, will update question with what I tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found out that this problem is related to the character encoding of eclipse console and not related to the `Java`.

I have used the same code and used `Run Configuration`  differently as shown below,

[image]

Now after running the program I got following output in my console,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\temp\??.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:95)
    at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

***Conclusion*** : Here for `ISO-8859-1` encoding in run configuration `Scanner` will not be able to read those character properly from console because console has different character encoding and you will have `??` as a `filename`.

Please change character encoding for your console, I firmly believe you are using some IDE. May be you have changed or your console inherited character encoding which is not suppose to encode those characters.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what you meant, Cp1252 is what I had originally, and yep changing it to UTF-8 fixes it

Comment: @TAsk Very nice catch!

Comment: Then what's the point of using a char set for encoding in the outputstreamwriter? Is there a way to do this without changing the encoding of eclipse?

Comment: @TAsk okay what if I have some other method of inputting characters into the program? because the example in the question was just a simplified one for the purpose of a SSCCE, in reality I have a save dialog where the user can type in their filename as well as a load dialog which can load in their filename.