# Java File with filename in UTF-8

Tags: java, file, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm writing a web application running on Tomcat.

Within this web application I want to create/save files like this:

```
File destFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
destFile.createNewFile();
```

Now the tricky thing is that the fileName is a UTF-8 encoded string. Unfortunately all UTF-8 characters such as German umlauts get replaced by "?" in the name of the file which is actually created.

So a fileName "hellö.txt" ends as "hell?.txt".

How can I fix this?

I'm running on a Ubuntu 14.04 server and as far as I can see everything is setup to support UTF-8.

I already added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to the JAVA_OPTS but this did not help.

Cheers.

Comment: What does `locale -a` say in the OS where Tomcat runs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java read write unicode / UTF-8 filenames (not contents)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171565/java-read-write-unicode-utf-8-filenames-not-contents)

Comment: I believe this is a defect that can be worked around by using alternate APIs for creating the file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171565/java-read-write-unicode-utf-8-filenames-not-contents

Comment: locale -a gives:C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

In my case it was not a Java bug. Instead, the locale settings on my server were broken. After fixing this like described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue it is now working even with `java.io.File` .

Answer (score -1):

Even when it's possible, which I am not sure about, it's a really bad practice to include characters like 'ö', 'ä' in file names. Instead, you should replace them with their synonyms 'oe' or 'ae'.

I wrote a basic function to do this for "german umlauts"

```
string removeBadCharacters(String string) {
    string = string.replace("ö", "oe");
    string = string.replace("ä", "ae");
    string = string.replace("ü", "ue");
    string = string.replace("ß", "ss");
    return string;
}
```

Yould then just pass your fileName and use the formatted string:

```
File destFile = new File(path + "/" + removeBadCharacters(fileName));
```

Comment: That's a pretty limited solution for the vast range of unicode characters that are possible; it won't work for your Japanese or Korean or Hebrew-speaking users. Unicode in file names has been effectively supported since the 1990s. For what it's worth, this appears to be an old Java bug. I'll post a reference to the solution above.

Comment: @JasonTrue yeah you are probably right about that. Totally forgot that unicode is much more than 'ä's and 'ß's. And if you say that unicode file names are supported there is a better solution.

Comment: Thx, but as JasonTrue outlined this is not a very suitable solution.