# Java 8 dealing unicode characters in file names unexpectedly

Tags: java, file, groovy, unicode, nio

I am frustrated to find a solution to the issue as explained in the question title. To help you understand clearly my problem, I am presenting below a little detail.

I have some files having an accent in their names which are storing in a directory. Running `ls -lht`, it cannot show the files correctly. The accents are decoded incorrectly. But if I press the `tab` key to apply autocompletion from the terminal, the file name can be shown as expected. See the snippet below.

```
tc_pst03@login-01: 6] ls -lht
total 704K
-rw-r----- 1 tc_pst03 pst_pub 86K Oct  9 00:27 Li??2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.cps
-rw-r----- 1 tc_pst03 pst_pub 46K Oct  9 00:27 Li??2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.xml
-rw-r----- 1 tc_pst03 pst_pub 11K Oct  9 00:27 Li??2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.sedml
tc_pst03@login-01: 6] mv Liò2012_Modelling\ osteomyelitis_Control\ Model.
```

When using a Java snippet to get all those files, I get the results which are `Li??2012...` instead of `Liò`. I have looked for shared solutions in our communities but no solution works for my problem. Below is the Java snippet I have tried to get the list of those files.

```
List<File> get(String modelId, int revisionNumber) throws ModelException {
        File modelDirectory = new File(modelCacheDir, modelId)
        File revisionDirectory
        List returnedFiles = new LinkedList<File>()
        try {
            revisionDirectory = new File(modelDirectory, revisionNumber.toString())
            if (!revisionDirectory.exists()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException()
            } else {
                returnedFiles = Files.list(revisionDirectory.toPath())*.toFile() //revisionDirectory.listFiles().toList()
            }
            if (returnedFiles?.isEmpty()) {
                String message = """The cache directory of this model ${modelId} revision ${revisionNumber} is empty. \
 The model cache builder will be launched again."""
                throwModelException(modelId, message)
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException me) {
            String message = """The files associated with this model ${modelId}, \
revision ${revisionNumber} hasn't been cached yet"""
            throwModelException(modelId, message)
        }
        return returnedFiles
    }
```

I suspected JVM does use the default charset so I manually enable UTF-8 by defining it in `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS`: `export JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"`.

Some results are printed below:

```
[
._Li?2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.xml4483388255187556135.tmp, 
._Li?2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.xml8578169841449575225.tmp,
Li��2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.sedml, 
._Li?2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.xml1056906750418910165.tmp,
Li��2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.xml, 
Li��2012_Modelling osteomyelitis_Control Model.cps]
```

I need to get those files' names to compare with the same files names persisted in the database. However, the file names getting from the file system are decoded improperly so it is never equal to the ones already saved in the database.

Do anyone know why the issue is happening. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: check filename encoding with app that creates those files. is this app located on remote server?  what your terminal gives you for command `locale charmap` ?  try to configure terminal to see filenames correctly in utf-8 - then switch to java.

Comment: @daggett: the terminal shows encode characters in the file names but the terminal can show exactly the special characters as the autocompletion. I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @daggett: ```Files.copy(it.toPath(),
                    new File(modelRevDir, fileName).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)``` does keep the same file name if the name has an accent?

Comment: for me sounds strange that `ls` displays filenames incorrectly. what encoding do you have  configured in terminal (`locale charmap` on linux) ? is there a remote dir where you are reading/writing files?

Comment: the command `locale -a` got me `homes/tc_pst03/devtools/linuxbrew/bin/locale: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.23/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`. Yes, the directory is on Network File System. I read this post `https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171886/865603` confirmed that `Files.copy` does the same.

Comment: you can see the production site shows the file names correctly at https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/BIOMD0000000923#Files. However, I ran the same source code to do some data clean at the back end and hit into the same directory and database, I face to the issue.

Comment: i believe it's not connected with the java code. i had similar situations with NFS file staring between windows/unix systems. i'd start with setting up locale and making linux filesystem commands like ls/copy work correctly with accented filenames.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238040/discussion-between-tung-and-daggett).